# Transition probability matrix of a Markov chain from stationary distribution

Tags: markov-chains

I have given the stationary distribution $\pi=(1/9,3/4,5/36)$ of a connected Markov chain, which I don‘t know. Is it possible to generate the transition probability matrix of a Markov chain that has this stationary distribution?

Comment: There are 9 unknowns and only 5 equations.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Metropolis-Hastings algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm)